# Regular expression "swatch monitor log file output"

Tags: perl

In the /var/log/messages, I will get a output off IDS. like this:

```
Feb  4 13:24:17 test1-1 snort[4535]: [122:1:1] (portscan) TCP Portscan [Classification: Attempted Information Leak] [Priority: 2] {PROTO:255} 10.0.0.1 -> 10.0.0.2
```

What I do is , I monitor the /var/log/messenges file with **swatch**, and swatch will send the the logging output to a python script, and this will inform some manager with a smartphone.

So I want a more detail output to the manager. The setting I use:

```
watchfor /.*(.*test1-1.*TCP Portscan.*).*/
       exec command /usr/local/bin/send_msg "user" "$1"
```

Output will be this:

```
 test1-1 snort[4535]: [122:1:1] (portscan) TCP Portscan
```

But I want something like this, the ip address is always random:

```
 test1-1 TCP Postscan 10.0.0.1 -> 10.0.0.2
```

How can a do this? with regular expression?

kind regard

from your friendly sysadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will capture the interesting portions:

```
watchfor /(test1-1).*(TCP Portscan).*} (.*)/
       exec command /usr/local/bin/send_msg "user" "$1 $2 $3"
```

Comment: A nice...This helps me a lot...Have to do more digging in regex..:-((